# How can I replace the white rectangle within an image using ImageMagick?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

**Overview:**

The first picture is my original image. Here I want to replace the white rectangle shown with another image.

[image]

**My approach:**

I have created a mask image using `floodfill` and it looks as:

[image]

**Problem:**

Now I would like to get the distance or co-ordinates of the rectangle in the second image so that I can use those co-ordinates to overlay a new image on top of the first (original image) here.

I got a little idea to use ImageMagick's [chebyshev](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#chebyshev) morphology operator, but don't know how I can do that.

Comment: Try `convert image.jpg -threshold 90% result.jpg`

Comment: Or maybe `convert image.jpg -threshold 90% -canny 0x1+10%+30% result.jpg`

Comment: Hello Mark...thanks for the reply. but what I want here is to get the co-ordinates, rotation angle and width and height of the rectangle in order to overlap another image. Please see my other question here so that you get an idea what I am trying to achieve.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971894/replacing-detected-object-in-a-frame-with-an-image-imageprocessing

Hope I am going in the right way. If not please guide me.
Currently I am following this way:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20269

Comment: I would do Hough Lines to get the 4 sides and then solve for the intersections to get the corners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can locate the shape pretty accurately with a simple threshold, like this:

```
convert image.jpg -threshold 90% result.jpg
```

[image]

and you can then do a Canny edge detection like this:

```
convert image.jpg -threshold 90% -canny 0x1+10%+30% result.jpg
```

[image]

The next things I would be looking at are, using the `-trim` function to find the trim box coordinates, like this:

```
convert result.jpg -format "%@" info:
320x248+152+40
```

I have marked that on in red below.

[image]

If you actually want to do the trim, use this:

```
convert result.jpg -trim result.jpg
```

[image]

And also, the deskew angle

```
convert result.jpg -deskew 40 -format "%[deskew:angle]" info:
-0.111906
```

A Hough line detection may also be effective for you like this:

```
convert image.jpg -threshold 90% -canny 0x1+10%+30%      \
    \( +clone -background none                           \
              -fill red -stroke red -strokewidth 2       \
              -hough-lines 5x5+80 -write lines.mvg       \
    \) -composite hough.png
```

[image]

And the file `lines.mvg` contains the 4 lines you are looking for

```
# Hough line transform: 5x5+80
viewbox 0 0 640 360
line 449.259,0 474.432,360  # 90
line 0,72.5604 640,27.8072  # 143
line 0,293.098 640,248.344  # 187
line 153.538,0 178.712,360  # 153
```

Being a bit lazy, I didn't feel like solving for the intersections of those lines, so I thought I'd let ImageMagick do that too - by using Morphology to look for Line Junctions like this:

```
convert image.jpg -threshold 90% -canny 0x1+10%+30%                        \
  \( +clone -background none -fill red -stroke red -hough-lines 5x5+80 \)  \ 
     -composite -fuzz 50% -fill black -opaque white                        \
     -morphology HMT LineJunctions hough.png
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the effort. I will give it a try as soon as I upgrade my imagemagick to 6.9. I have 6.7 and thus was unable to use -canny which supports in 6.8 onwards i guess

Comment: Mark one more question for you. How can I store the co-ordinates of the dots(intersections) which you have used for display purpose, in a variable or a file, the way you did it with lines.

Comment: should work with `convert hough.png txt:- | grep "red"`