# How to fit image into another image

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to fit an image into an exact position of another image. Therefore I need to

1. find the area in image ([see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973677/how-can-i-replace-the-white-rectangle-within-an-image-using-imagemagick#30977177))
2. scale and fit the overlay image into the original image file.

---

**Example**

My original image will have something similar to a white page:
[image: origianl Image]

Now I have to find the white rectangle and replace it with the overly image:
[image: The overlay example]

---

**Result**

The result should look something like that:
[image: Final result]

Comment: Solve for the intersection of the lines... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973677/how-can-i-replace-the-white-rectangle-within-an-image-using-imagemagick/30977177?noredirect=1#comment50717904_30977177

Comment: yes, but it doesn't return coordinates... as I recommend in the command of that post, you can look for the pixel color. But it doesn't work reliable...

Comment: Thats what I want, just with imagemagick: http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Imagemagick (>6.8) I can detect the more or less detect the white rectangle with the following command:

```
convert example.jpg -threshold 40% -canny 0x1+10%+30%    \
    \( +clone -background none                           \
              -fill red -stroke red -strokewidth 2       \
              -hough-lines 50x50+80 -write lines.mvg     \
    \) -composite result.png
```

[image: Imagemagick convert result]

It also return me the line coordinates (lines.mvg).

```
# Hough line transform: 50x50+80
viewbox 0 0 1280 720
line 0,198.011 1280,63.4774  # 280
line 802.382,0 840.115,720  # 97
line 0,675.347 1280,518.183  # 238
line 138.716,0 201.708,720  # 191
```

*Later I want to implement the solution for the equation suggested by [mark-setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370236/how-to-fit-image-into-another-image#31372867).*

You can let imagemagick look for the intersections...

```
convert example.jpg -threshold 40% -canny 0x1+10%+30%  \
  \( +clone -background none                           \
        -fill red -stroke red -strokewidth 1.2         \
            -hough-lines 50x50+80                      \
  \) -composite -fuzz 50% -fill black -opaque white    \
     -morphology HMT LineJunctions result2.png
```

[image: intersection points result2]

Like in this example, you will no only have to look for red points but also for reddish pixel:

```
convert result2.png txt:- | egrep "red|srgb\(2[45][1234567890]"
# 808,112: (255,  0,  0)  #FF0000  red
# 807,113: (254,  0,  0)  #FE0000  srgb(254,0,0)
# 809,113: (254,  0,  0)  #FE0000  srgb(254,0,0)
# 155,183: (245,  0,  0)  #F50000  srgb(245,0,0)
# 832,572: (255,  0,  0)  #FF0000  red
# 196,652: (247,  0,  0)  #F70000  srgb(247,0,0)
```

Now its time to clean close by points...

```
points=`convert result2.png txt:- | egrep "red|srgb\(2[45][1234567890]" | sed -n 's/^\([0-9]*,[0-9]*\).*$/\1/p'`
close=100

clean=()

distance()
{
    echo $(( ($1 - $3) * ($1 - $3) + ($2 - $4) * ($2 - $4) ))
}

while read x1 y1
do
    ok=1
    for point in "${clean[@]}"
    do
        echo "compare $x1 $y1 with $point"
        set -- $point
        if [[ $(distance $x1 $y1 $1 $2) -le $close ]]
        then
            ok=0
            break
        fi
    done
    if [ $ok = 1 ]
    then clean+=("$x1 $y1")
    fi
done < <( echo -e "$points" | tr ',' ' ' | sort -u )

echo "Clean:"
printf "%s\n" "${clean[@]}" | tr ' ' ','

edge_points=`printf "%s\n" "${clean[@]}" | tr ' ' ','`
```

And order them...

```
# get Center
centerx=0
centery=0
for point in $edge_points; 
do
    x=$(echo "$point" | cut -d, -f1)
        y=$(echo "$point" | cut -d, -f2)
    if [ $centerx -eq 0 ]
    then
        centerx=$((x))
        centery=$((y))
    else
        centerx=$(( centerx+x ))
        centery=$(( centery+y ))
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done

centerx=$(( centerx/i ))
centery=$(( centery/i ))


centercircle="circle $((centerx-1)),$((centery-1)) $((centerx+1)),$((centery+1))"
echo "final center point $centercircle"

# Determine top-left, bottom-left, top-right, and bottom-right corner
top=()
bot=()

for point in $edge_points; 
do
    x=$(echo "$point" | cut -d, -f1)
        y=$(echo "$point" | cut -d, -f2)
    if [[ $y -le  $centery ]]
    then
        top+=("$x $y")
    else
        bot+=("$x $y")
    fi
done

echo "top points:"
printf "%s\n" "${top[@]}" | tr ' ' ','
echo "botten points:"
printf "%s\n" "${bot[@]}" | tr ' ' ','

top_points=`printf "%s\n" "${top[@]}" | tr ' ' ','`
bot_points=`printf "%s\n" "${bot[@]}" | tr ' ' ','`

[ $(echo ${top[0]} | cut -f1 -d ' ' ) -gt $(echo ${top[1]} | cut -f1 -d ' ' ) ] && tl=${top[1]} || tl=${top[0]}
[ $(echo ${top[0]} | cut -f1 -d ' ' ) -gt $(echo ${top[1]} | cut -f1 -d ' ' ) ] && tr=${top[0]} || tr=${top[1]}
[ $(echo ${bot[0]} | cut -f1 -d ' ' ) -gt $(echo ${bot[1]} | cut -f1 -d ' ' ) ] && bl=${bot[1]} || bl=${bot[0]}
[ $(echo ${bot[0]} | cut -f1 -d ' ' ) -gt $(echo ${bot[1]} | cut -f1 -d ' ' ) ] && br=${bot[0]} || br=${bot[1]}
echo "lt: $tl"
echo "lr: $tr"
echo "bl: $bl"
echo "br: $br"

clean_ordered=()
clean_ordered+=("$tl")
clean_ordered+=("$tr")
clean_ordered+=("$br")
clean_ordered+=("$bl")

edge_points=`printf "%s\n" "${clean_ordered[@]}" | tr ' ' ','`

# draw result
radius=2
nr=1    
circles=$(for point in $edge_points; do
          x=$(echo "$point" | cut -d, -f1)
          y=$(echo "$point" | cut -d, -f2)
          # use IM to do some floating point math, EG:  y2=$y+$radius
          y2=$(convert xc: -format '%[fx:'"$y"'+'"$radius"']' info:)
          echo "circle $x,$y $x,$y2"
        done)

echo "$circles"

text=$(for point in $edge_points; do
          x=$(echo "$point" | cut -d, -f1)
          y=$(echo "$point" | cut -d, -f2)
      x=$((x+5))
      y=$((y+5))
          echo "text $x,$y \"$nr\""
      nr=$((nr+1))
        done)

# Draw blue circles on the 4 points and the center point.
convert result2.png \
        -draw "fill none stroke blue $circles " \
        -draw "fill none stroke blue $centercircle" \
    -pointsize 20 \
    -draw "fill blue stroke blue $text " \
        result3.png
```

[image: show founded points and center point]

Now we have all the value we need to finally composite the image. Just some more variables are missing:

```
points_a=`printf "%s\n" "${clean_ordered[0]}" | tr ' ' ','`
points_b=`printf "%s\n" "${clean_ordered[1]}" | tr ' ' ','`
points_c=`printf "%s\n" "${clean_ordered[2]}" | tr ' ' ','`
points_d=`printf "%s\n" "${clean_ordered[3]}" | tr ' ' ','`

orgi_size=$(identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" test/example.jpg)
owidth=$(identify -format "%[fx:w]" test/overly.png)
oheight=$(identify -format "%[fx:h]" test/overly.png)
```

---

Now we can draw the final result, there fore we use `-distort perspective` method (*thats the answer for the 2. question*):

```
convert \
    -verbose \
    example.jpg \
        \( overly.png \
        -background none \
        -gravity NorthWest  \
        -extent $orgi_size \
        -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent \
        -distort Perspective "0,0 $points_a  $owidth,0 $points_b  $owidth,$oheight $points_c  0,$oheight $points_d" \) \
    -composite result4.jpg
```

[image: final automatic resolve image]

Answer (score 1):

I had assumed you would be able to solve the equations, but I can show you how if you are stuck.

Let's look at the first two lines listed. They are straight lines so they can be represented by an equation of the form

```
y = mx + c
```

where `c` is the y-intercept and `m` is the gradient of the line.

So, with the first line, the intercept, or `c` is clearly 198 since it crosses the x axis there. If we put in some other values (I'll ignore decimals as they just confuse the concept) you will get

```
63 = 1280m + 198
```

So, the equation of the first line is

```
y = -135x  + 198
    -----
     1280
```

The second line can be discovered using similar triangles to get the y-intercept, or `c` so

```
 38   =  802
---      ---
720       c
```

which means

```
c = -802 * 720
    ----------
        38
```

if we then put in the values we have listed for the second line into the formula again, we get

```
720 = 840 m  - 802*720
               -------
                  32
```

which means

```
m=18.95
```

and the second line's equation is

```
y=18.95x -15196
```

So, if we set the two y values equal, which must be the case where they meet

```
-135x   + 198  = 18.95x - 15,196
-----
1280


-135x = 23,687x + 19,242,500
```

Therefore x=807 and substituting that in the equation of line 1, y=112.

So the first two lines intersect at 112,807.

I'll let you do the other three...

Comment: Thx for the example, but thats only one part of the problem... I'll try to write a general equation when I have time to solve the other three intersection. I found a faster way to find the intersection... I'll post it soon.